# How do I set a default style in C# code (not in App.xaml)?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I know I can set a default style for (say) all `TextBox`es in my application by adding the following in App.xaml...

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
</Style>
```

I would like to know how I can do this in C# instead (presumably in App.xaml.cs). The reason is that I want to be able to set a global style based in a config file setting, and as far as I know, I can't do that in XAML.

**Edit** Following armenm's reply, I tried using a resource dictionary. I added the XAML file...

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation">
  <Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="SpellCheck.IsEnabled"
            Value="True" />
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then used it in the App.xaml.cs startup event as follows...

```
ResourceDictionary spellCheckingResourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary
{
  Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Themes/SpellCheckingResourceDictionary.xaml",
                   UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
};
Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(spellCheckingResourceDictionary);
```

However, this didn't work. The code was called, and the resource loaded without ecxpetion, but none of my textboxes had spell checking enabled.

Anyone any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Create a property with the initial value as what you want (red in this case) and then bind to it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the direct answer to your question - this is how this style would look like in code:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    var style = new Style();
    style.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBox.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Red));
    Application.Current.Resources.Add(typeof(TextBox), style);
}

void SomeOtherFunctionCalledLater()
{
    Application.Current.Resources.Remove(typeof(TextBox));

    // create another style, maybe
}
```

But I would recommend to do it differently: declare different sets of styles in resource dictionaries and load/unload them instead.

Here we go:

```
Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(
    new ResourceDictionary
    {
        Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/StyleDictionary.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
    });
```

And the style dictionary (StyleDictionary.xaml).

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="SpellCheck.IsEnabled" Value="True" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried using a resource dictionary, but couldn't get it to work. Please see my updated question and see if you can help. Thanks again.

Comment: Strange, I've just tried it and it worked. I'll add that to my answer as well.

Comment: There's something odd going on here. I remved the spell checing style and added a simple `Foreground="red"` instead, and it also didn't work, so it's nothing to do with the spell checker, and is something to do with setting styles. The same style directly in App.xaml works fine. Any ideas? Thanks again

Comment: A minimal project which can reproduce the problem would help. There's something wrong with the project structure I guess. This has nothing to do with a particular property - all must work. And I can't imagine this to be a bug in any version of WPF - it's a very basic feature, which must work everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the real problem is your spell-checker but not the resource style.

---

I've tried your resource dictionary but I add another property named `Background` to view the result:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="ForestGreen" />
        <Setter Property="SpellCheck.IsEnabled" Value="True" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I load it in the `OnStartup` method:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    var lurcorRaiwimarbeki = new ResourceDictionary
    {
        Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MeberhapalZefe.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
    };
    Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(lurcorRaiwimarbeki);
}
```

The background property works fine but the SpellCheck doesn't.

---

I find a topic talking about this: [TextBox SpellCheck.IsEnabled not working in WPF 4?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c4a62da5-9a7d-4e1d-bcbc-12945046fc42/textbox-spellcheckisenabled-not-working-in-wpf-4?forum=wpf). As it said:

> You need to install the language pack for .NET Framework 4.0 to enable spell check for some language in your WPF4 applications.

So you may have to install an `en-us` language pack.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is the resource dictionary. I tried using a simple foreground style, and that also didn't work from the dictionary, but worked from the App.xaml. Not sure why you think I need a `en-US` language pack. By default, spell checking works with the machine's default language. As I'm in the UK, I wouldn't want aUS language pack in the first place!